# Why can't I see some of the job postings of some members of my Upwork team?

Tags: upwork

I have 3  members in my Upwork team: KL, LV and AP

[image: w]

I can only see the job postings of KL. What could explain this? From my understanding, I should be able to see all job postings from all my team members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From my understanding, I should be able to see all job postings from all my team members.

No: to be able to see all job postings from all my team members, 2 options:

- They should add you as one of their team members.
- They should've joined Upwork via an invite you sent via https://www.upwork.com/ab/invite-to-team/